# iOS app is failing to build with an exception after implementing ViroReact AR library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I'm currently working on a React Native App which has some AR functionality. After installing ViroReact and following the all iOS linking process from here https://github.com/ViroCommunity/viro/blob/main/readmes/INSTALL_IOS.md. I'm getting some exception right before app launch. Below is the screenshot of error I'm getting. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: you should use Unity for AR app.